# If $R$ is not reflexive, then exist $R^*$ such that $R \subset R^*$ and $R^*$ is reflexive.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I tried to solve this, but I don't think it is right.
I suppose that $R$ is not reflexive and $R \not\subset R^*$ or $R^*$ is not reflexive.

Case 1: $R$ is not reflexive and $R \not\subset R^*$

We have that $R$ is not reflexive then $(x,x) \not\in R$, then $(x,x) \in   R^c$. And $R \not\subset R^*$ then $R^c \subset R$, since $(x,x) \in R^c$ then $(x,x) \in R^*$. Thus $R^*$ is reflexive.

Comment: In the title, do you mean "and $R^*$ is reflexive"?

Comment: I think your task is to construct $R^*$ satisfying this condition.

Comment: $R$ not *reflexive* means that there is an $a \in X$ such that $(a,a) \notin R$. You have to find a suitable $R^*$ on $X$ such that $R \subset R^*$ and $R^*$ is reflexive, i.e. $(a,a) \in R^*$ for every $a \in X$.

Comment: You can try "adding" to $R$ all $(a,a)$ such that $a \in X$.

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt thank you, i didn't notice that. 
And i don't know since there's an 'exists' can i show just one and make no proof?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA can i assume that R* is reflexive since the begining? Or i just need to show and example where this works?

Comment: No; you have to show that it exists, for example "manufacturing" it.

Comment: You can also try $R^\ast = \{(x,y) | \, x\in X,\,y\in X\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I_X = \{ (a,a) \in X^2 \mid a \in X \}$ be the identity relation on $X$, and let $R$ be any relation on $X$. Then $R^* = R \cup I_X$ is reflexive and contains $R$. At this point, you should try to prove the claim. If you get stuck, then you can read the rest of this post for the solution.

Certainly, $R \subset R \cup I_X = R^*$, so $R$ is contained in $R^*$. To show reflexivity, let $x \in X$ be arbitrary. Then $(x,x) \in I_X \subset R \cup I_X = R^*$. Thus $R^*$ is reflexive.

Note that proof just given actually shows a stronger result. Whenever $R,S$ are two relations on a set $X$ and at least one of $R,S$ is reflexive, then the union $R \cup S$ is also reflexive.

Comment: thank you, know i understand more. One last question, can i use the same method to demostrate (symmetric, antisymmetric and transitive?)

Comment: @LexieWalker, I'm not sure what you mean. If you mean, "Can I show that $R^*$ is symmetric and/or antisymmetric and/or transitive?" then the answer is no. $I_X$ is the smallest reflexive relation, and so the $R \cup I_X$ is the smallest reflexive relation containing $R$. If you want to construct a (different) $R^*$ containing $R$ that turns it into a symmetric (or antisymmetric, or transitive) relation, you will need a different idea.